# String Manipulation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

How to Manipulate row information in different columns for one column information in Excel. For example I have this information in Column A , row24

**(  0.) 385496.635062,5821996.493247  -->  0**

I want to separate this information such that

Column B ROW24  contains (0.)

Column C ROW24  contains 85496.635062

column D ROW24  contains 5821996.493247

Column E ROW24  contains 0

As I want to further perform some Mathematical Operations on this datasheet.

I need Excel Function to Manipulate 150 rows of information.

Regards,

Adnan Ali Ch.

Comment: Why was this post down voted? It is a perfectly normal question for 'excel-Formula"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in B24 =left(A24,4)
in C24 =mid(A24, 7,12)
in D24 =mid(A24, 20, 13)
in E24 = right(A24,1)
```

This is just parsing out the text.
If there are changes to the text that follow some rule, those can be incorporated into the formulas.